# XML elementtree one at a time in memory

Tags: python, xml, parsing, multiprocessing

I have quite a large xml file and relatively little memory. Whilst parsing the file, i am currently loading the entire file into memory as seen in the code snippet below which slows the whole computer down and sometimes doesnt even work. I was wondering if there is a way to only load one item into memory at a time? Perhaps using some multiprocessing like in deep learning when the next file is loaded whilst the current one is being processed.

```
root = ET.parse("my_file.xml").getroot()

for child in root:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 2):

There's only one mention of the word "memory" in the entire **etree** documentation, and it's in the context of [iterparse()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) not reading the whole XML into memory:

> If you don’t mind your application blocking on reading XML data but would still like to have incremental parsing capabilities, take a look at iterparse(). It can be useful when you’re reading a large XML document and don’t want to hold it wholly in memory.

However, the docs don't show any example of how to use iterparse. PyMOTW 3 has [a really good write-up](https://pymotw.com/3/xml.etree.ElementTree/parse.html) on the entire etree module and includes an example of iterparse.

Without any more context on what `do_something()` does, the simplest implementation for you would look like:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

for _, elem in ET.iterparse('input.xml'):
    do_something(elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.iterparse` function. Parse large XML files incrementally. This is good for large XML files where you don't have to load the whole file into memory.

From the [documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse)

> **xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse(source, events=None, parser=None)**
>
> Parses an XML section into an element tree incrementally, and reports what’s
> going on to the user. source is a filename or file object containing XML data. events is a sequence of events to report back. The supported events are the strings `"start"`, `"end"`, `"comment"`, `"pi"`, `"start-ns"` and `"end-ns"` (the “ns” events are used to get detailed namespace information). If events is omitted, only `"end"` events are reported. parser is an optional parser instance. If not given, the standard XMLParser parser is used. parser must be a subclass of XMLParser and can only use the default TreeBuilder as a target. Returns an iterator providing (event, elem) pairs.

It's a blocking function, so it's not asychronous. If you have several XML readers at the same time:

> Note that while `iterparse()` builds the tree incrementally, it issues blocking reads on source (or the file it names). As such, it’s unsuitable for applications where blocking reads can’t be made. For fully non-blocking parsing, see `XMLPullParser`.